# Facebook Api: (#10) Notification send blocked

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I´m trying to send notification on facebook using the /[userId]/notifications but I get this error:

{"error":{"message":"(#10) Notification send blocked.","type":"OAuthException","code":10,"fbtrace_id":"DaJz4OMIMLC"}}

My code is working on my development environment (accessing a develop Facebook App), but when I try on my Production environment I get this error.

Anyone can help me?

thanks

Comment: That probably means you send too many notifications, resp. that they got to little user engagement. Facebook expects you to maintain a certain CTR for notifications – and if you fall below that, your app might be blocked from sending any more. Facebook does this to prevent spam apps from pestering users with notifications they don’t care about.

Comment: You are right! I tried with another login and works. Thanks